# How do embed button and prompt() box?

Tags: php, prompt

I am trying to embed button add prompt box as:

```
<?php
 echo "<input type='button' name='ok'onclick=prompt('Enter Your email address')value='OK'>";
?>
```

Its not working. Moreover, On button click a prompt box will appear and user will enter his/her email address and as he/she hit enter email has to b sent on entered email id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Arguments with whitespace need to be closed in apostrophes or quote marks.

2) Your code is using apostrophes for both inside of the `onclick` and the `prompt`.

```
echo "<input type='button' name='ok' onclick='prompt(\"Enter Your email address\");' value='OK'>";
```

Comment: Huge thax...! One query is completed but i need code that will able to send email to inputted email address..! please provide code that works !